# React-Native wrong dimension length in Android?

Tags: react-native

I'm facing an issue where apparently, when using `useWindowDimensions()` on React-Native, the length of the shortest dimension is incorrect.

Minimum reproducible example: Create an app from scratch using `npx react-native run-android` and paste the following on `App.js`:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <View
        style={{
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          position: 'absolute',
          top: useWindowDimensions().height - 20,
        }}>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Explanation: there's a red-colored view of size 100 x 100 positioned absolutely on the screen. By doing `top: useWindowDimensions().height - 20`, I'm telling the view to move all the way to the bottom, and just to "peek" 20 dps.

On portrait orientation, it works:

[image]

But on landscape, it doesn't work. The view doesn't peek from the bottom

[image]

In fact, the view is still hidden at the bottom. Subtracting `20` from the height of the screen was not enough. I played around and found that I need to subtract at least `28` to make it visible:

[image]

What's going on? I would have expected that `useWindowDimensions().height` returned 28 less than what it did. Is this a bug? Or am I missing/not considering something else?

Note: at the beginning I thought it could be because of Android's status bar or navigation/action bar. But that doesn't make sense...because IT WORKS with a Portrait Orientation.